# WYSIWYG TinyMCE editor only works for my Administrator

Tags: wysiwyg

Since updating to Drupal 7.31 the WYSIWYG TinyMCE editor only works for my Administrator Role.  For my Manager Role it *now* only works with Comments and Blocks but not for Articles and Blogs.

Comment: check the permissions. and try rebuilding the permission and clear cache. :) hope that helps

Comment: Are you running multiple text formats? It sounds like you'r text formats got mixed up at some point (as your manager can use the WYSIWYG but in blocks and comments, but not nodes). Head to MYSITE/admin/config/content/formats, and check to make sure the text format that uses the wysiwyg widget is floated to the top. That text format that is first on that list should be the default. If it's not, drag it up to the top of the list, that might fix it.

Comment: Yes I had that set up OK.  I just updated to 7.31 and all my sites got this bug.  Very strange to me.